# Variable number of arguments in C++ [Xcode]

Tags: c++, xcode6

I have a problem with variable number of arguments in C++. I write my code using Xcode.

Here is my code:

```
#include <iostream>

int sum(int n, ...)
{
    int *p = &n;
    p++;

    int res = 0;
    for(int i=0; i<n; i++){
        res+=(*p);
        p++;
    }

    return res;
}

int main(int argc, const char * argv[]) {

    std::cout << sum(4, 1, 2, 3, 4);

    return 0;
}
```

`sum(4, 1, 2, 3, 4)` should return a value of 10, but it returns 1606452732.

Comment: Where did you read that this was the right way to write a variadic function? As of C++11, it's changed to variadic templates in the general case anyway (and you'd get by on an initializer list here).

Comment: I'm not sure what they're trying to teach, but this reeks of undefined behaviour. There are standard `va_start` etc. macros for accessing variadic arguments, but you still can't guarantee a safe function call (for example, `sum(2, 5, 2.5)` seems reasonable, but will fail catastrophically if you assume both are `int`). Variadic templates and other modern methods will actually cause the normal compiler errors you'd see elsewhere in type safety, as well as getting rid of that ugly length argument.

Comment: @Smolik: This was *never* legal C++.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In C++ you use a template metafunction to do that. It's pretty straight forward:

```
int sum(int u)
{return u;}  // Recursion-End

template<typename... Args>
int sum(int u, Args... rest)
{
    return u + sum(rest...);
}
```

Try it [online](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/53bc23d4f5c1b5ee)!

However there is a, as I consider it, depreciated C-way using `va_start` and `va_end`. You need to include `cstdarg` and on function call you need to provide the total parameter count. It would look like this:

```
int sum(int argnum, ...)
{
    va_list arguments;
    int i;
    int sum = 0;

    va_start(arguments, argnum); /* Needs last known character to calculate
                                    the address of the other parameters */
    for(i = 0; i < argnum; ++i)
        sum += va_arg(arguments, int); /* use next argument */

    va_end(arguments);

    return sum;
}
```

Try it [online](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/54ccd36e613079bd)!

Comment: Soon it will be even easier with C++1z fold expressions: [`u + (rest + ...)`](http://goo.gl/tJDq1u). Calling with (1,2,3,4) would expand to `1 + (2 + (3 + 4))`, and no need for more than one function! About the link destination, you can see the `$15` result on the right. Unfortunately, I don't know of any other online C++1z compiler.

Comment: @chris Yeah, I'll be pretty excited when this becomes standard!̣

Comment: Wait, I'm still learning, and I was wondering how to get this to be a left fold, too. [`return (u + ... + rest);`](http://goo.gl/nW2Ib0)

Comment: @chris Didn't you already come up with it? [Same](http://goo.gl/rhhD8H) asm-output, just removed the struct....

Comment: Oops, didn't realize I left that in there. I was about to use that to test when I got a left fold and then realized this binary form would do that before actually testing.

Comment: C-style variable argument lists are not deprecated in C++. And they're certainly not depreciated; they never had much value to lose.

Answer (score 0):

From: http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/variadic/va_start

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cstdarg>

int add_nums(int count, ...) 
{
    int result = 0;
    va_list args;
    va_start(args, count);
    for (int i = 0; i < count; ++i) {
        result += va_arg(args, int);
    }
    va_end(args);
    return result;
}

int main() 
{
    std::cout << add_nums(4, 25, 25, 50, 50) << '\n';

    return 0;
}
```